# Iteration and conditions vs many ActionListener classes in java

Tags: java

I am wondering if iterating and putting many if-statements instead of creating many inner classes that extend ActionListener could somehow degrade the performance of my program.

Here is the situation:

The app has many buttons, each button have unique test and unique actionPerformed() code. To shorten the code, I thought of iterating each button and using conditional if-statements to get the correct actionPerformed() code for the correct button.

Does using that algorithm somehow affect the program? 
Which is better?

**The Iteration and Conditions**

```
public class Sample {
    JButton one = new JButton("1"); 
    JButton two = new JButton("2");
    JButton three = new JButton("3");
    JButton four = new JButton("4");
    JButton five = new JButton("5");
    JButton[] buttons = {one,two,three,four,five};

    for (button:buttons) {
        button.addActionListener(new buttonListener);
    }

    public class buttonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            for (button:buttons) {
                if (button.getText.equals("1")) {
                    //some code here
                }
                if (button.getText.equals("2")) {
                    //some code here
                }
                if (button.getText.equals("3")) {
                    //some code here
                }
                if (button.getText.equals("4")) {
                    //some code here
                }
                if (button.getText.equals("5")) {
                    //some code here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**or The Many Classes**

```
public class Sample {
    JButton one = new JButton("1");
    JButton two = new JButton("2");
    JButton three = new JButton("3");
    JButton four = new JButton("4");
    JButton five = new JButton("5");
    one.addActionListener(new OneKeyListener);
    two.addActionListener(new TwoKeyListener);
    three.addActionListener(new ThreeKeyListener);
    four.addActionListener(new FourKeyListener);
    five.addActionListener(new FiveKeyListener);

    public class OneKeyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            //some code here
        }
    }
    public class TwoKeyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            //some code here
        }
    }
    public class ThreeKeyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            //some code here
        }
    }
    public class FourKeyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            //some code here
        }
    }
    public class FiveKeyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            //some code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tag description of code-review: **DO NOT USE THIS TAG TO ASK FOR A CODE REVIEW OF YOUR CODE. Please use codereview.stackexchange.com to request a code review of otherwise working code.***. This kind of question is off-topic here but you wan ask it in [codereview.se]

Comment: @Kepotx Except you should avoid redirecting off-topic questions to code review. This one is off-topic there for containing stub code.